# Using the HAVING clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-apex

I am trying to get the employees whose income is greater than 80% of the total average. The problem is that the HAVING clause doesn't works as it throws the following error.

> This is the error in line of the HAVING (column 38):
>   **ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply**

How can I fix the query to use HAVING correctly?

```sql
SELECT 
  e.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || e.LAST_NAME as name,
  sum(o.order_total) as income
FROM  EMPLOYEES e, ORDERS o
WHERE e.employee_id = o.sales_rep_id 
GROUP BY e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME
HAVING sum(o.order_total)*0.8 > avg(sum(o.order_total))
ORDER BY sum(o.order_total) DESC;
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please add only the relevant one - the answer may depend on the software that you are using.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is it that you have a comma where you should have a decimal point? Is it something else? If so, what? Please [edit] your question to include some sample data, the result you would expect for that sample data and what the issue/error is with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your existing query, you could use a window function to compute that grand average, and use it for filtering in the `having` clause:

```
select 
    e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name name,
    sum(o.order_total) income
from employees e
inner join orders o on e.employee_id = o.sales_rep_id 
group by e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
having sum(o.order_total) > 0.8 * avg(sum(o.order_total)) over()
order by sum(o.order_total) desc;
```

Notes:

- always use *explicit* joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins
- I added the id of the employee to the `group by` clause to prevent wrongly grouping possible homonyms

---

Alternatively, you can use a subquery:

```
select name, income
from (
    select 
        e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name name,
        sum(o.order_total) income,
        avg(sum(o.order_total)) over() avg_income
    from employees e
    inner join orders o on e.employee_id = o.sales_rep_id 
    group by e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
) t
where income > 0.8 * avg_income
order by income desc;
```

Comment: This appears to give `ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply`

Comment: Error in the same line (column 38):
> ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply
> 00935. 00000 -  "group function is nested too deeply"

Comment: @MT0: my bad, I was too ambitious with window functions. I added a second query to my answer that is more reasonable...